# How to pull a docker image from Jfrog Artifactory using K8S

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, jenkins, artifactory

I have a local repository in Jfrog artifactory on EC2.
when I try pulling the image using only docker everything goes well, but when I try to pull it using K8S deployment.yaml I get **ImagePullBackOff** and this is the logs when running the describe on pods.
Any Ideas on what might be the problem? Thanks.

```
Events:
Type     Reason     Age                     From               Message
----     ------     ----                    ----               -------
Normal   Scheduled  8m50s                   default-scheduler  Successfully  assigned default/weatherapp-dep-6f79c6c774-kln95 to ip-172-31-23-92
Normal   Pulling    7m27s (x4 over 8m49s)   kubelet            Pulling image "54.235.13.197:80/moodyslocaldockerhub/weatherappjdka:v1.49"
Warning  Failed     7m27s (x4 over 8m49s)   kubelet            Failed to pull image "54.235.13.197:80/moodyslocaldockerhub/weatherappjdka:v1.49": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "54.235.13.197:80/moodyslocaldockerhub/weatherappjdka:v1.49": failed to resolve reference "54.235.13.197:80/moodyslocaldockerhub/weatherappjdka:v1.49": failed to do request: Head https://54.235.13.197:80/v2/moodyslocaldockerhub/weatherappjdka/manifests/v1.49: remote error: tls: alert(112)
Warning  Failed     7m27s (x4 over 8m49s)   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
Warning  Failed     7m1s (x6 over 8m48s)    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
Normal   BackOff    3m44s (x20 over 8m48s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "54.235.13.197:80/moodyslocaldockerhub/weatherappjdka:v1.49"
```

Comment: When you say you use "docker pull and everthing goes well", is that on the same k8s node where this pod is running?

Comment: yes, pulling the image from the Artifactory using only docker in the CLI works. but when declaring the image path in the yaml file so it can be pulled using K8s give the above error.

Comment: Might it be that your local Docker is configured to trust insecure registries? The port 80 implies you are on http and not https. You need to get your K8s to also trust insecure registries. Look up your k8s vendor's docs. Hint in the error "remote error: tls"

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `imagePullSecret` or a service account with the credentials to the repository.

---

the manifest looks like this

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregistrykey
  namespace: awesomeapps
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: <base64_of_credentials>
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

or alternatively generate it with this command

`kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>`

---

Then you mount the secret

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I still get the same error.